# NS and SOA records not propagated after migration from Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, domain-name, nameservers, a-records

I recently transferred a domain `helloorbital.com` from GoDaddy to Route 53. However, when I used [WhatsMyDNS](https://www.whatsmydns.net/#SOA/helloorbital.com) to check my SOA and NS records, they are still pointing to the old registrar's records, how can I get my records to properly propagate please?

Separate question for knowledge, shouldn't my records on Route 53 take precedence once I migrate, why is it that it hasn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-transfer-to-route-53.html#domain-transfer-to-route-53-up-to-five-procedure), you have three options for DNS when you transfer your domain to Route 53:

- Continue to use the name servers provided by the current registrar or DNS service
- Import name servers from a Route 53 hosted zone that has the same name as the domain
- Specify new name servers to replace the current registrar's name servers (not recommended)

The implications of changing the DNS are significant and thus default option is to continue to use the name servers provided by the current registrar or DNS service.

To resolve the issue you are facing, you need to get the nameservers for your Route 53 Hosted Zone by following the steps [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/GetInfoAboutHostedZone.html), and then replace the nameservers for your domain in Route 53 by following the instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-name-servers-glue-records.html#domain-name-servers-glue-records-procedure), replacing the existing name servers (ns1.vodien.com and hostmaster.serveradd.com) with the four name servers provided by the Route 53 Hosted Zone.

DNS propagation can take up to 48 hours, however, in many cases it occurs in a matter of minutes.